# combineReducer does not work in combination with redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import authSlice from './auth/auth-slice';
import generalSlice from './general/general-slice';
import userSlice from './user/user-slice';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// Define persistConfig
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root', // key for the root state
    storage: AsyncStorage, // use AsyncStorage as the storage engine
};

const persistedGeneralReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, generalSlice.reducer);
const persistedUserReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userSlice.reducer);
const persistedAuthReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, authSlice.reducer);

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: persistedAuthReducer,
  general: persistedGeneralReducer,
  user: persistedUserReducer,
})


const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'CLEAR_STATE') { // check for action type 
    state = undefined;
  }
  return combinedReducer(state, action);
};

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
  auth: persistedAuthReducer,
  general: persistedGeneralReducer,
  user: persistedUserReducer,
},
  middleware: [thunk]
});

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export const clearState = () => ({
  type: 'CLEAR_STATE'
});

export { store, persistor };
```

With the config above, everything works, so when I directly put the persistedReducers into the configureStore, I have no issues with my application. But the thing is that when a user logs out, I want to clear the redux state and I came up with the solution of using a rootReducer and a combinedReducer and then setting state = undefined to clear the state, but when I put the rootReducer as value for `reducer:` , redux-persist stops working, and when I reload my application all my redux states are gone.

I have tried to use combinePersistedReducer but it did not work aswell.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue usually implement this by set all reducers to initial state.

```
const initialState = {
 user: '',
 mail: ''
}

const myReducers = (state = initialState,action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "EMAIL": 
            return {
                ...state,
                mail: action.payload.mail
            }
        case "USER":
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload.user
            }

        case "CLEAR_STATE":
            return initialState
        default: 
            return state  
    }
}
```